# Adding inputs through for loop

Tags: javascript, html

How do I change this code so that when I select an input it adds the text from array based on input id. I have tried to do it myself, but in for loop "i" is always equal to 2, but I want it to be 0, 1 based on which input I select. Please help, I have spent multiple hours with no success.

```js
let basetext = [];

let text1 = document.getElementById("text")
text1.innerHTML = basetext



const thank = [`hi`,
`bye`]


for (i=0; i<thank.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("thank"+i).addEventListener("click", function () {
            basetext[i] = thank[i]
             text1.innerHTML = basetext.join('')
        })
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <textarea id="text"></textarea>

    <div class="buttons">
      <div>
        <div>
          <input type="radio" name="thank" id="thank0" />
          <label for="thank0">first</label>
          <input type="radio" name="thank" id="thank1" />
          <label for="thank1">second</label>
        </div>
        <button>Next</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to each input.
2. Add a class to a containing element, and then use [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/) to catch events from the child input elements when they're fired. In the handler check to see if the child element that fired the event is a radio input, and then use the data attribute to grab the element from the `thank` array, and update the textarea content with it.

```js
// Cache the elements
const text = document.querySelector('#text');
const group = document.querySelector('.inputGroup');

// Add one listener to the input group element
group.addEventListener('change', handleChange);

const thank = [`hi`, `bye`];

// Check that clicked input is a radio button,
// grab the id from its dataset, and then use
// that id to add the element from the array to
// the content of the text area
function handleChange(e) {
  if (e.target.matches('[type="radio"]')) {
    const { id } = e.target.dataset;
    text.defaultValue = thank[id];
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
<div class="buttons">
  <div>
    <div class="inputGroup">
      <label for="0">first
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="thank"
          data-id="0"
          id="thank0"
        />
      </label>
      <label for="thank1">second
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="thank"
          data-id="1"
          id="thank1"
        />
      </label>
    </div>
    <button>Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. I will try to understand the code you wrote, some parts are new to me, though.